# Creating a matrix in Mathematica with Pure Functions

Tags: function, matrix

I know how to create a one-dimensional array in Mathematica by using pure functions and mapping over a range. The syntax is as follows:

# & /@ Range[1,3]

This returns:

{1, 2, 3}

I would like to know how to create a two-dimensional array with a similar syntax. The two- dimensional array returned would be:

{ {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} }

The syntax I had hoped would work is:

{#1, #2} & @@ {Range[1,3] , Range[1,3]}

(or something similar), but this instead returns:

{ {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3} }

You can use the Table[] function to create this matrix of ordered pairs, but the pure function syntax seems more dynamic, perhaps.

Comment: `# & /@ Range[1,3]` ?!?  Why not just `Range[3]` ?  `# &` is just a (pure) identity function, I can't see any reason for using it. And for the 2D array just `Table[{i,j},{i,3},{j,3}]`.  I don't understand at all why you are using such a convoluted approach to simple list generation.  Which makes be think I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: HPM, Thank you for your reply. The reason I wanted to avoid using Table[] is that, as far as I know, you cannot change the number of indices you are tabling over. In reality, I want to make a function f[x_], where x is the number of indices I am tabling over. In other words, f[3] would give Table[{i,j,k},{i,4},{j,4},{k,4}]. I thought that the pure function syntax would be more flexible than the Table[] syntax in this regard. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: My friend proposed this syntax:

Function[{a}, {a, #} & /@ Range@3] /@ Range@3

for the two dimensional array I was looking for, but I have yet to mess around with this to see if I can make a rank 3 tensor, etc.

Comment: What is the point of posting questions, such as yours above, which do not ask what you really want to know, as you have now revealed in your comments ?